# Linux - Can you share wireless connection to ethernet connected to a router acting as an "access point"?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, router, wireless-access-point

This is my setup

```
Main router -> Linux box (connected with Wireless interface) -> Ethernet interface
on the computer -> Router that acts as an "AP"
```

The computer is running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Can I do this? If so, how can I do it?

**P.S. Please just don't ask me why I want to do this mess.**

Comment: Whatever you are doing, why not use the Router as a regular Router. That is why they do for a living and you have one.

Comment: Instead of subjectively calling this a mess, you might want to elaborate on the root problem and your goal. You might be lucky and someone can recommend you a much better and easier solution. By the way, this exact thing is called a [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Ues, you can do it.  You need to bridge the WIFI and ethernet imterface.  I believe you wpuld install tje "bridge-utils" package. Im mot use the "sanctioned" way to do tjis in Ubuntu, but "brctl addbr bridge0;  brctl addif bridge0 ethX; brctl addif bridge0 wlanX" or similar should work. You might need to remove the IP address from the eyhernet and use it on the bridge0 device instead.

Comment: your computer cannot bridge at layer 2 Wireless because it's a client (STA) and this requires 4 addresses mode everywhere. Only an AP can bridge Wireless out of the box. So you've got routing left.

Comment: details about 4 versus 3 addresses (while Ethernet uses 2) with Wifi: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header . The only mode with 4 addresses is used for "WDS" so only 3 addresses are used by default. with 3 no bridging from the client (only from the AP).